# Fetch FullCalender.io Event Objects (JSON) from Database for a specific date-range

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fullcalendar

I have a huge database and a lot of events. Every time I go to the Calendar Mainpage (monthly view) all the existing events in the database are loaded, despite I'm only viewing the current month. At the moment my html page is over 3MB big and tends to slow down my browser tab.

To solve this problem I started to change the code to fetch only the events from the current month as json. Unfortunately, the start and end dates for the date-range are not working - the page is still fetching all events from the database. I have already done a few hours of research and a lot of tweaks.

**[Im using FullCalendar V3.10](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v3.10.0)**

So far I managed to fetch my FullCalendar.io events - I have two event sources - so I used:

```
eventSources: [
    {
        url: 'include/load-calendar-event.php', // use the `url` property
        color: '#008000',   
    },              
    {
        url: 'include/load-calendar-event-retour.php', // use the `url` property
        color: '#008000',
    },                          

    // any other sources...
],
```

The corresponding two files to fetch the events are almost identical - so one should be enough:

**load-calendar-event.php**

```
require_once('bdd.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages"; // this selects all rows
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();
$events = $req->fetchAll();

$data = array();

foreach($events as $event) {
    $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
    $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
    if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
        $start = $start[0];
    }else{
        $start = $event['start'];
    }
    if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
        $end = $end[0];
    }else{
        $end = $event['end'];
    }   

    $data[] = array(    
        'id'=> $event['id'],
        'title'=> $event['title'],                              
        'start'=> $start,
        'end'=> $end,
        'color'=> $event['color']   
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

By calling the Calendar Page the browsers makes the following calls - please note the date (2020-01-01 - 2020-02-01) and data format:

```
...include/load-calendar-event.php?start=2020-01-01&end=2020-02-01&_=1578601056565
```

and

```
...include/load-calendar-event-retour.php?start=2020-01-01&end=2020-02-01&_=1578601056566
```

[screenshot of call in firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm980.png)

The date format of the events are saved in the database with the following format *(YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss):*

```
2020-01-11 10:00:00
```

**Question:**

Any idea how to fetch the events ONLY for the current month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you selecting all the rows in the table and iterating over them?

You need to update your query to pull in the start and end values you're passing as a `$_GET` parameter.

```
require_once('bdd.php');
$sdate = $_GET['start']; //LIKE THIS
$edate = $_GET['end']; //AND THIS
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE date >= ".$sdate." AND date <= ".$edate; // this selects all rows.  Change 'date' to whatever your column name is in the database.
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();
$events = $req->fetchAll();





$data = array();

foreach($events as $event) {

    $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
    $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
    if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
        $start = $start[0];
    }else{
        $start = $event['start'];
    }
    if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
        $end = $end[0];
    }else{
        $end = $event['end'];
    }   

    $data[] = array(    
        'id'=> $event['id'],
        'title'=> $event['title'],                              
        'start'=> $start,
        'end'=> $end,
        'color'=> $event['color']   
    );

}


echo json_encode($data);
```

You could do this more easily by simply using PHP's date function to generate the start and end dates instead of passing in variables with your query string params.  Although this will give you more flexibility.  You can even include some if/else statements to generate different queries if these values are set.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Hi, thx so far. Any idea how to change the date format? i tried your code and it returns no events - i guess its due to the different date formats...

Comment: what format is the date in the database and what is the field set as? YYYY-MM-DD  Within mysql run this query and post the output.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE messages`

Comment: The format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` and set as datetime in the database.

Comment: This concept is good but OP should be warned that is is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL like this. The way this code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete the data.